# What might cause a Null Reference Exception when creating an empty list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

### Update

This seems to be a problem with stepping over methods in Visual Studio and not directly related to the content of the Linq statements. Inorder to exersise this section of code I was skipping over some time consuming methods using the debugger - if I instead of skipping over them, make them just return on the first line, the error goes away.

I have a repeateable example of the following code throwing a null reference exception on the last line:

```
            List<Product> testList = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product
                {
                    Sku = "sku"
                }
            };
            string sku = testList.First().Sku;

            var simpleQuery = testList.Select(p => p.Sku);

            List<string> skus = simpleQuery.ToList();
```

But this ONLY happens if I skip the debugger over a method (even if the method I skip looks like this):

```
    private bool DoSeomthing()
    {
        return false;
    }
```

I'd be interested to know if anyone can reporoduce this or has any ideas what might cause it...

### original

I have stumbled on some rather odd behaviour in a relatively routine piece of code that confusing and I'm not sure how to investigate further.

It seems that when I try to instantiate a List and then use that list in a more than one LINQ query, the initial instantiation throws a null reference exception.

The first line of this code throws 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

I've commented out the actual repository code, but just using new List() still throws.

```
List<Product> testProducts = new List<Product>();
                               // _repo.Products().ToList();


List<Product> deleteProducts = 
    testProducts .Where(p => !(importProducts.Select(ip => ip.Sku).Contains(p.Sku))).ToList();

List<Product> addedProducts = //new List<Product>();
    importProducts.Where(p => !(testProducts.Select(ip => ip.Sku).Contains(p.Sku))).ToList();
```

If I change the declaration of addedProducts to a new List rather than a linq query then the code runs just fine.

How can the line:

```
List<Product> testProducts = new List<Product>();
```

throw a null reference exception?

Might be some strange compiler optimization error or something? Why does this happen? What can be done to resolve it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Product is an Entity Framwork version 6.0.0.0 object. I've tried restaring Visual Studio, Cleaning the solution, restarting the machine - but no joy. As usual in such odd cases, I'm sure this exact same code was working last week...

Comment: That line will never ever throw a `NullReferenceException`, your mistake is in somewhere else

Comment: Im confused. Which line throws an exception, the first?

Comment: @Selman22 That's exactly what I thought! Short of letting you remotie onto my machine and watch it do it I'm not sure how to show you that it actually does. Hence this question

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov - yes - the first. Which seems impossible. Which is why I think it might be a compiler optimization issue

Comment: Maybe importproducts is null?

Comment: Could `_repo.Products()` be returning null?

Comment: @Rand Random -importProducts has a 2038 items in - looks legit (also  it's used successfully in the first link method)

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov  As noted - the repo is commented out and it stil fails, so it can't be that :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically I find when I am stumped about a `NullReferenceException` with Entity Framework it is not because what I am doing *returns* null, so much as I am trying to *reference a property of a null*.

As an example, `FirstOrDefault()` returns a null if no item is found, however:

```
string Name = db.Items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 1).Name;
```

Will throw a `NulReferenceException`, because when a `null` is returned from the call, it can't get the `Name` property of it.

My advice would be to split out your nested calls into separate variables and pass them in, so you can isolate which expression is actually returning a null.

The other thing that can be confusing is EF's deferred execution - often the line that throws the error is **not** the line that caused it, it's just the unfortunate line that happened to execute the erroneous statement.

Comment: Good call. The IDE seems to be giving totally the wrong position of the exception - breaking down all the linq calls into seperate lines moves point where the exception is thrown to one of the Select clauses - which is much more sensible :)

Comment: Although splitting up the lines moved the error - the linq doesn't seems to be the issue... I have managed to reproduce the error in a much simpler linq statement. It's the ToList() bit that fails (because that's were the excecution happens) - but this only under certain debugger conditions (see update)

Comment: I've accepted your answer because it answers the original question - the new List() throwing was a red herring in the IDE - although I still don't understand why an exception is thrown at all...

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, here was my code:

```
if (true)
{
    List<Product> addedProducts;
    addedProducts = new List<Product>();    // Works
}
else
{
    List<Product> addedProducts;
    addedProducts = new List<Product>();    // Throw Exception
}
```

The solution was to move the declaration at the beginning of the method:

```
List<Product> addedProducts;
if (true)
    addedProducts = new List<Product>();    // Works
else
    addedProducts = new List<Product>();    // Works
```

The compiler let you declare two variables with the same name in a different scope of the same method but when you try to initialize in the `else` you get a `NullReferenceException`.

You can also have a look at the generated IL (and include it in your question).

Answer (score 0):

> If I change the declaration of addedProducts to a new List rather than
>   a linq query then the code runs just fine.

It's extremely likely that the error is in this statement then.

Check all of the objects in this statement and make sure they are instantiated.  Are you sure `anotherTestProducts` is not null?

Sometimes it can be misleading in what lne VS highlights when an error is thrown.

Comment: Sorry - anotherTestProducts was a typo - there should be no variables in the second linq call that are not in the first - and the first one works...